# Why do my Clementine Icons look like gnome default?

Tags: 13.04, icons, clementine

I am talking about the icons inside Clementine, not the indicator icons or unity launcher icons. I mean the ones almost on the bottom of the screen previous track, play, pause, next track.
After i installed ubuntu 13.04 and clementine fresh it looked like it should: Black and white icons in black circles. (I'd love to upload a picture but as this is my first question, it seems that i can't because i need 10 rep points to do so)

Now, (i think after i added the Cinnamon-stable repo, but i'm not entirely sure) those icons look like some kind of gnome default, an ugly stale grey.

Can anybody tell me why that is and more importantly, how i can get it right again? I figured it might have something to do with qt style settings in my unity environemt. Am i thinking in the right direction? I know it's a minor thing but it drives me nuts.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem on ubuntu 20